# Error in Emacs flycheck mode with rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, rubocop, flycheck

I use flycheck mode with rubocop checker.

when I open some rb file,

```
Checker ruby-rubocop returned non-zero exit code 1, but no errors from output: /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2157:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fc38c8edb10 rubocop-0.35.1> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1056:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:63:in `require'
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rubocop-0.35.1/bin/rubocop:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Checker definition probably flawed.
```

And flycheck mode is not working

I also use projectile / projectile-rails mode. But rb files of some projects are not raise errors. Error is occured some project.

Comment: does rubocop runs ok from command line? generally it happens for two kind of reasons, 1) rubocop.yml has some issue 2) you are using rvm,  if its a rubocop.yml issue you will easily able to see it by running rubocop from command line, if it is rvm, then you may need rvm-use (https://github.com/senny/rvm.el)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell you what is going on without seeing it run on the command line.

I had the same error, and it turned out I was using an older version of Rubocop, and the FlyCheck was calling the `rubocop` executable with an option that it didn't understand (`--display-cop-names`).

So run it from the command line, and post the results and then we can try to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was seeing this:

```
/Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fce0dc538dc rubocop-0.47.1> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rubocop-0.47.1/bin/rubocop:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/alexmoore-niemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

But this problem was only in one of my projects;`rubocop` executed fine in another project!

So I uninstalled rubocop, ran [`gem update --system`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-update), then reinstalled it, and it worked again in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after:

```
$ rubocop --auto-gen-config
```

in my Rails APP_ROOT, all works fine now.